# Perform OCR via MODI on specific region instead of entire document

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, ocr, modi

I am trying to get to perform bulk OCR on images in a selected directory via MODI. Here's the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog {
                InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users",
                IsFolderPicker = true
            };
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok) {
                invoicePath = dialog.FileName;
                CheckFileAndDoOCR(imageDirectory);

            }
        }

public string CheckFileAndDoOCR(string directoryPath) {
            string TheTxt = "";
            IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();

            while (files.MoveNext()) {
                FileInfo foo = new FileInfo(Convert.ToString(files.Current));

                if (foo.Extension == ".jpg" || foo.Extension == ".JPG") {
                    TheTxt = DoOCR(foo.FullName);
                    string txtFileName = foo.DirectoryName + "\\" + foo.Name.Replace(foo.Extension, "") + ".txt";
                    FileStream createFile = new FileStream(txtFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile);
                    writeFile.Write(TheTxt);
                    writeFile.Close();
                    createFile.Close();
                }
                try {
                    foo.Delete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            return TheTxt;
        }
public string DoOCR(string FullPath) {
            MODI.Document miDoc;
            MODI.Word miWord;
            MODI.IMiRects miRects;
            MODI.IMiRect miRect;
            string strRectInfo;
            miRect = null;

            string txt;
            string word;
            MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
            md.Create(FullPath);
            md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false);
            MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
            txt = image.Layout.Text;
            word = null;
            image = null;
            md.Close(false);
            md = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            return txt;
        }
```

How can I perform the OCR on a specific area, for example

```
Rectangle Area = new Rectangle() {
                X = 1367,
                Y = 420,
                Height = 57,
                Width = 411
            };
```

I have to extract data from one region/rectangle only from all the images. How can I do that? I have tried IronOCR and Tesseract, works like a charm. But I have been told to use MODI. Please help.

Comment: Why would you consider using MODI, which was being used until Office 2007 instead an up-to-date tool like IronOCR or so?

Comment: Because its not my decision to make.

Comment: Of course, but I said that in terms of documentation, performance and stability.